# How to show the mediaElementPlayer in browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mediaelement.js

I face a really really simple problem when I try to use the mediaElementPlayer.js in web.
I just want to new a mediaElementPlayer object and show it in my website.
So I try their example in their website.

The first example works fine, it's like:

```
$('video,audio').mediaelementplayer(/* Options */);
```

What it does is to convert all video and audio tags to MediaElement.js using jQuery

But the second one, I have tried many times still can't make it work. The example is below

```
    // JavaScript object for later use
    var player = new MediaElementPlayer('#player',/* Options */);
    // ... more code ...
    player.pause();
    player.setSrc('mynewfile.mp4');
    player.play();
```

My code is:

```
var zsq = new MediaElementPlayer('player1',{
          alwaysShowControls: false,
          features: ['playpause','current','progress','duration','volume','fullscreen']

  });
  zsq.pause();
  zsq.setSrc('/video/bappleflx.mp4');
  zsq.play();
```

Anyone knows how to fix it? I think it is really simple but I just can't fix it!

Thanks

Comment: Define "can't make it work" - are there any errors in the console, what does console.log(player) show? Is this code executed after DOM is loaded?

Comment: @raina77ow Ya,you are right! The code used to build the MediaElementPlayer obj isn't executed. I has fixed the problem now. I write a video tag whose id="player". Then I can successfully new the MEP object. Thanks!

Comment: @raina77ow ok!Go ahead